# How to configure Port Forwarding for dynamic IP?

Tags: port-forwarding, dynamic-dns

My router gets different IP addresses. Dynamic DNS is enabled.

I have to configure port forwarding in my router.
While configuring port forwarding, I need to fill following details:

1. Internal IP
2. Internal Port
3. Remote IP
4. External Port
5. Protocol (TCP/UDP)

Please guide me to configure Port Forwarding in my router.

Regards
UGN

Comment: “I need to fill” – but do you? Simply leave out the remote IP.

Comment: @DanielB The remote IP is not the same thing as the local external IP, which is the only thing that's changing.

Comment: @MikeScott I know. That’s why I’m saying to leave it out. He most likely wants his port forwarding to be accessible by everyone, and not just some specific remote host.

Comment: @DanielB Sure, but that has nothing to do with a dynamic IP address, so it's not relevant to the question. If he just wants to know how to configure port forwarding, whether or not he has a dynamic IP, then that would need a new question.

Comment: @MikeScott I believe he is just confused about the (seemingly all required) fields. His comment on your answer also hints at that.

Comment: We have no idea what service your using so we can't answer the ports.  If it was a web service 80 and 443.  Most services use TCP. Internal IP only **you** know the IP of the device inside your network.  The source IP should be ANY.

Answer (score 1):

Just configure it the same as you would if you had a static IP address. None of those parameters will change when your external IP address changes, so the dynamic IP won't make any difference.

Comment: Please guide me to configure Port Forwarding and what details I need to fill in above fields.